# changing font size of ttk.combobox dropdown window

Tags: python, tkinter

I used ttk.Combobox to make a dropdown menu so that the user can select their sex ("sesso" in italian), and this is the code that i used:

```
sessi = ["M", "F"]

sesso_menu = ttk.Combobox(value=sessi, font=("Calibri", 16), state="readonly")
sesso_menu.place(x=4, y=4, height=32, width=52)
sesso_menu.current(0)
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcd9m.png) but now want to change the font of the two variables inside the window that pops up to make them bigger, how do i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.option_add()` to set the font but it applies to all `Combobox`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox.font", "Calibri 16")

...
```

Or you can get the *Popdown Window* of `sesso_menu` via TCL command and configure the font of the listbox inside the *Popdown Window*:

```py
popdown = root.tk.call("ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow", sesso_menu)
root.tk.call(f"{popdown}.f.l", "configure", "-font", "Calibri 16")
```

Comment: root.option_add("*TCombobox*Font", "Calibri 16") will also work.

Comment: Also `self.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox.font", custom_font)` works, where custom_font  is declared `= font(family, size)` and self is a subclass of tk.Frame.